# Is incrementing an integer (using +=) thread-safe in (recent versions of) Ruby?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, thread-safety

I have used the following Python code to show that it is not thread-safe to increment an integer `i` on multiple threads:

```
>>> i = 0
>>> def increment_i():
...     global i
...     for j in range(1000): i += 1
...
>>> threads = [threading.Thread(target=increment_i) for j in range(10)]
>>> for thread in threads: thread.start()
...
>>> for thread in threads: thread.join()
...
>>> i
4858  # Not 10000
```

I have tried to translate this code to Ruby, expecting similar results:

```
> $i = 0
> def increment_i()
>     for j in 0...1000 do $i += 1 end
> end

> threads = (0...10).map { Thread.start { increment_i } }

> for thread in threads do thread.join end
```

If I run this Ruby code on version 1.8, it does indeed behave the same as the Python code, leaving `$i` with a value less than 10000.

However, on 1.9 and 2.3, `$i` always seems to be set to exactly 10000.

Is incrementing an integer using `+=` in fact thread-safe in Ruby 1.9 and later?

Comment: The global interpreter lock in MRI 1.9 and later makes your code effectively thread-safe.

Comment: @Stefan - Was the GIL changed between 1.8 and 1.9, or was it new in 1.9? Is its behaviour documented anywhere?

Comment: IIRC, 1.8 had green threads. However, you should not rely on this behavior. If you have a critical section, put it in a [`Mutex#synchronize`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Thread/Mutex.html#method-i-synchronize) block. You can install JRuby for testing purposes.

Comment: This question shows that you should not rely on your intuition: MRI has green threads which the runtime schedules itself, and it can *never* schedule two threads to run at the same time. Yet, it returns the wrong result. YARV has system threads which are scheduled by the operating system, and so YARV has no control over which thread runs when and on which CPU core. YARV only has a Global VM Lock that protects two Ruby threads from entering the interpreter at the same time, and over the last years there has been work on breaking up the lock, so that more code can run concurrently. Yet, it …

Comment: … returns the correct result. It would be easy to assume that MRI would be safe, since two Ruby threads can never run at the same time. But that is wrong, for two reasons: one, the operation itself is not atomic, so a thread switch may happen in between, and two, both assignment and `+` is not actually Ruby code, it is C code, and C code *can* run concurrently in MRI.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, Ruby does not have a well-defined memory model like e.g. Java or C++ do. So, the *general* answer to questions about thread-safety and atomicity is: no-one knows, but you should assume the worst.

There is no way of knowing how any particular Ruby implementation will behave. As you have noticed, MRI and YARV behave differently. (You were assuming the difference is due to Ruby 1.8 vs. Ruby 1.9, but that is wrong, the difference is due to MRI vs. YARV.) Rubinius may behave one way or the other, or a completely different way. Same for Opal, Topaz, Ruby+OMR, TruffleRuby, MagLev, MRuby, IronRuby, JRuby, and whatever else may come along in the future.

However, in this specific case, we can actually get a more satisfying answer than the general "no-one knows":

```
$i += 1
```

is just syntactic sugar for

```
$i = $i + 1
```

which clearly is two operations and thus clearly non-atomic. The fact that it appears to work on YARV, is due to a private internal implementation detail that is not guaranteed, may change at any moment without notice, and may or may not exist on other implementations.

Comment: So, `$i += 1` is essentially two operations and therefore, in general, non-atomic. Are there any operations that Ruby _does_ guarantee to be atomic, across all implementations?

Comment: Like I said, there is no defined memory model. You simply don't know. The way it works in Ruby is basically like this: you write some code that works on YARV but doesn't on JRuby. Now, you get into an argument whose code is correct: yours, YARV's, or JRuby's. Either JRuby needs to change to match YARV, YARV needs to change to match JRuby, or *your* code needs to add some synchronization. And the result of this discussion could be called as some kind of tiny part of a memory model specification.

Comment: There are some expectations in the Ruby community about what is atomic and what isn't, and an implementation that violates this is not going to be accepted. But really, pretty much the only thing that is universally accepted to be atomic, is variable assignment. And *only* variable assignment, i.e. no indexing assignment (`[]=`), no method assignment (`foo.bar=`), and no compound assignment (`a += b`).